# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; to set permission

Tags: mysql, puppet

this is my command to give grant permission to the user to the database

grant all on 'puppet'.* to 'puppet'@'%';

Answer (score 0):

Looking in depth on [this page about granting permission](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/):

1. It looks like you're trying to create a superuser ? If so, you're missing one `*` On your command, which should be like this :

`grant all priviliges on *.* to 'puppet'@'%'`

2. If you're not creating a superuser, then your command should be like this :

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';`

Hope this helps !